# Subsonic 2.0.3: Save() causes problem due to identity field constraint

Tags: sql, subsonic, constraints

Here's a strange one.  I'm using SubSonic 2.0.3 to insert a new row into a given table.

The table includes an int identity field that is set up properly in the database (Identity seed = 1, Identity increment = 1).  Obviously I do not explicitly set this value before calling .Save().

Ever since I rebuilt my development DB (copying from my prod DB), the .Save() fails with the message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
> "repl_identity_range_tran_661577395". The conflict occurred in
> database "blah", table "dbo.ScheduledEmails", column 'MyIdentity'

The database is replicated, and I didn't explicitly create that constraint.  To be honest, I don't understand the constraint, since the condition is ([MyIdentity]>(7) AND [MyIdentity]<(20000)).  The constraint from the Prod DB has different numbers, but it's the same format as this one from my Dev DB.

Any clues about this bizarre issue?

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a subsonic problem. It won't create constraints for you.